# The basis for an eigenspace

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

47. $A$=
    \begin{bmatrix}
        -4 & 8 & -12 \\
        6 & -6 & 12 \\
        6 & -8 & 14
      \end{bmatrix}

with $\lambda = 2.$ What is the basis for the eigenspace of $A$?

Solution: $\begin{bmatrix}
    x_1 \\
    x_2 \\
    x_3
  \end{bmatrix}
$ $= x_2\begin{bmatrix}
    \frac{4}{3} \\
    1 \\
    0 
  \end{bmatrix}
$ $+x_3 \begin{bmatrix}
    -2 \\
    0 \\
    1
  \end{bmatrix}
$

The eigenspace is a 2 dimensional subspace of $\mathbb{R}^{3}$.

A basis is $\begin{bmatrix}
    4 \\
    3 \\
    0 
  \end{bmatrix}$, $\begin{bmatrix}
    -2 \\
    0 \\
    1 
  \end{bmatrix}$.

Hello, I just wanted to check if my solution was correct please. Someone told me it was not but I'm not sure how it is wrong. Thank you.

Comment: Yup. The system is degenerate so the eigenspace is indeed a 2 dimensional subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$. The two eigenvectors that you find sufficiently compose the basis of that subspace.

Answer (score 1):

Your eigenvectors$$ \begin{bmatrix}
    4 \\
    3 \\
    0 
  \end{bmatrix}$$

$$ \begin{bmatrix}
    -2 \\
    0 \\
    1 
  \end{bmatrix}$$ are correct.

Your eigenspace associated to $\lambda =2$  is the two dimensional space generated by these eigenvectors as you have mentioned.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback!